# VB NET How to execute some code at the start and at the end of any function

Tags: vb.net, function, reflection, benchmarking

I like to try to optimize my code, and I would like to measure the time taken by a function.

I have a class named Chrono. So I just have to add chrono.start at the beginning of the function, and chrono.stop at the end. My class chan also add the times it measure in a list, to then have average time, total time...

It works. Only problem is when there is exit sub or return in the middle of the function. Not really a problem, I just add a Try at the begginf of the function, and put my chrono.stop in the finally portion. I'm not sure it's really efficient, but it works.

So here is my question : I would like to have a function taking function name as parameter, that will automatically launch and stop my class when this function is called. I have heard of Reflection, but I have no idea how to use it. And it's really hard to search for this question in the internet (because the words are too common : "do something at the end of a function")

To resume, my code works, no problem. It's just constraining to add code to a function for just a short period of time (and sometimes forgot to remove it).

Thx (I'm french and hope I'm understandable)

Comment: The correct way to do this would be to use a profiler, not rolling your own timer.

Comment: I rembember there is an AOP way of doing it; anyway, if you just want to measure performances, you might want to try the VS Diagnostic Tools. EDIT: Although the AOP will be opt-in.

Comment: I can use the profiler of visual studio. However, The loading of the application is slower, end it's long to have the results because it measures everything. But maybe there is a way to tell it what to measure... I will look into that. Isn't there a way to do it as I asked ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use reflection to call a method by name:

```
using System.Reflection;

public int InvokeMethod(string name)
{
    int time1 = 1; //call your chrono.start here.
    Type thisType = this.GetType();
    MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(name);
    theMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { 1 });
    int time2 = 10; //call your chrono.end here.
    return time2 - time1;
}
```

However, there is a problem. How will you know what parameters to pass to the function? In the code above, I'm passing the integer 1 (`new object[] { 1 }`) just for example. So this code cannot be automated, but if you run it manually against each function one by one, then you can change that line to pass the correct arguments and make it work without having to modify your function.

This is to answer your question as how to call a function by name using reflection. However, it is much easier to call it using a `delegate` (or `Fuc<T, tRsult>` in .Net v3.5 and higher).

Comment: Hi. Thx for your answer. However, I would like to DETECT when a specific function is launched, and when it finishes. This way, I could start my measure just before the specified function is launched, and stop it after its execution. I (approximately) know how to use delegate to start a function from another function.

Comment: Yes, in the code above, replace the `int time1 = 1;` line with your `chrono.start` and the `int time2 = 10;` with your `chroho.end` after, just like I said in the comments, and you get exactly what you wanted. You can achieve exactly the same with deligates, just replace the three lines between `time1` and `time2` with the call to the delegate.

Comment: What is more, calling a function via reflection is going to be significantly slower than a normal call to that function, so this will certainly throw off your timings. Non-real-world timings are worse than useless.

Comment: @CodyGray Fully agree. Reflection should never be used for timing. A `delegate` or `Func<>` are the way to go when there is a need for indirect call. In the scenario where you manually test each function, I'd simply use direct call because none of those solutions offer any benefit. However, if you automate the code by -for example- providing an array of functions to the delegate and run them in a loop (assuming they have the same signature, or you provide the arguments in the array as well), then the `delegate` comes in handy.

Comment: The code you provide, if I understand correctly, is meant to  start a function, and add code before and after. But if I use this, I would have to redo all my function call. What I want (maybe it's not possible) is a sort of event handler that can detect when a function is start. If I have to change all my function call, I better modifying directly the function itself to add the timer. Let's say I have a function named "calculatethis()". What I wish is to be able to add at the start of the app "WatchandMeasureFunction("calculatethis"), without modifying anything anywhere else.

Comment: I cannot think of any way to detect when a function start without modifying the function itself to raise that event. Events are not magic, they are just functions used in a certain way. They don't just run by themselves, you need to raise them which is similar to how you call normal functions. However, I'm not sure if the dependency injection pattern can be useful here. Maybe somebody else skilled in that pattern can add a comment here.